# Refactoring JavaScript functions that differentiate only by condition and return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have 3 functions which are really similar. They differentiate only in input parameter name, condition and return value. I'm going to refactor them, and I thought you guys might tell me what is the best way in your opinion to refactor these. Feels like there has to be 1 function but with understandable name and the condition should be passed as the function in parameter or something like that.

```
function getFieldName(fieldName) {
    var dataSet = getDataSet();

    var dataFields = dataSet.DataFields;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
        if (dataFields[i].FieldName.toLowerCase() === fieldName.toLowerCase()) {
            return dataFields[i].FieldName;
        }
    }
    return null;
};


function getFieldNameByDisplayName(displayName) {
    var dataSet = getDataSet();

    var dataFields = dataSet.DataFields;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
        if (dataFields[i].DisplayName.toLowerCase() === displayName.toLowerCase()) {
            return dataFields[i].FieldName;
        }
    }

    return null;
};


function getDisplayNameByFieldName(fieldName) {
    var dataSet = getDataSet();

    var dataFields = dataSet.DataFields;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
        if (dataFields[i].FieldName.toLowerCase() === fieldName.toLowerCase()) {
            return dataFields[i].DisplayName;
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

What do you think? Thank you.

====================================

> **Update:** may be something like this:

```
function getFieldName(fieldName, compareFieldProperty, returnFieldProperty) {
    var dataSet = getDataSet();

    var dataFields = dataSet.DataFields;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
        if (dataFields[i][compareFieldProperty].toLowerCase() === fieldName.toLowerCase()) {
            return dataFields[i][returnFieldProperty];
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rgraham. I've asked it there earlier, but no one answered and it barely has any views there. So, I decided to get response here. And got it, thanks StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a [dynamic property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) and pass the property names as parameters:

```
function getAbyB(a, b, bvalue) {
    var dataFields = getDataSet().DataFields;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
        if (dataFields[i][b].toLowerCase() === bvalue.toLowerCase()) {
            return dataFields[i][a];
        }
    }
    return null;
};


function getFieldName(fieldName) {
    return getAbyB("FieldName", "FieldName", fieldName);
}
function getFieldNameByDisplayName(displayName) {
    return getAbyB("FieldName", "DisplayName", displayName);
}
function getDisplayNameByFieldName(fieldName) {
    return getAbyB("DisplayName", "FieldName", fieldName);
}
```

Comment: I think this is golden... Very clean and easy to read. Thank you very much, Bergi.

Comment: Ah, you already have something very similar in your Update. You should use the parameter names from there instead of my uninspired `a`s and `b`s :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function getFieldName(type, name) {
    var dataSet = getDataSet();

    var dataFields = dataSet.DataFields;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
        if (dataFields[i][type].toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
            return dataFields[i][type];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```